# magento usps shipping free method does not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento version 1.9.3.2 and configured the usps shipping.All shipping methods are working fine but Now I want to show usps free method. I have enabled the free method and also setup with minimum amount or without minimum amount.But doesn't show any free method on front end.